# Get different results when evaluating indefinite integral multiple times

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying to evaluate the following indefinite integral in Mathematica:

```
Integrate[Exp[(k + g) t]/(1 + Exp[k t])^3, t]
```

When evaluating the integral multiple times I get the result in different forms (see the image). Out[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAn9E.png) and Out[2] are mathematically equivalent (I tested this using FullSimplify and by plotting them for several values of k and g). Out[3] is of course correct but not useful to me.

Does anyone know what's going on here? I'm not sure why the output is changing on subsequent evaluations.

Note: I already tried closing and reopening Mathematica and quitting the Kernel. This is happening in Mathematica 12.1.1.0 Student Edition Mac OS X.

[image: Figure showing issue.]

Comment: I can verify this. With a new kernel, the first, second and third time I get the above results.  Every additional evaluation reproduces the third result. This should be reported to support@wolfram.com

Comment: On v12.2.0 Win7-x64 I see the first variation three times in a row.

Comment: Thank you both. I reported the issue to support@wolfram.com.

Comment: With v13.0.1 on a Mac, all three results are identical, equal to your first result,  and verify as a valid anti-derivative.

Comment: With v12.3.1 on Win10-64, I only obtain your first result repeatedly.